# Вызов LPSolver из приложения на C++

Tags: c++

Скажите, пожалуйста, как из gui приложения на C++ вызвать LPSolver? Можно пример кода?

Comment: Что такое LPSolver ? Я погуглил  - там множество вариантов. 
И gui приложение на С++ - это Qt? Или что?  В Qt например есть класс `QProcess` для запуска внешних программ. В С++ можно использовать вызов `system()`.

Comment: Ошиблась, имела ввиду LPsolve http://lpsolve.sourceforge.net/5.5/ Приложение хотела сделать в microsoft visual studio или borland c++ builder.

Comment: Если вы знаете как запустить LPSolver в командной строке, то можете выполнить эту же команду с помощью вызова `system("тут ваша команда")`. Документация - [https://ru.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/program/system](https://ru.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/program/system)

Comment: Не знаю(  Я считаю в LPSolve IDE. Это графический интерфейс. Там записываешь в поле типа блокнота задачу лин программирования, используя специальный синтаксис. Мне, видимо, надо в программе на C++ такой текстовый файл создать. И вот думаю, куда его дальше передать, чтобы открылся LPSolve и посчитал.

Comment: Вы указали ссылку на страничку проекта, там есть документация, вы её читали ? У них же целое API есть, позволяющее делать видимо всё то же что и IDE которой вы пользуетесь. Вот например [функция](http://lpsolve.sourceforge.net/5.5/solve.htm) решающая модель. А вот -[полный перечень всех функций](http://lpsolve.sourceforge.net/5.5/lp_solveAPIreference.htm)

Comment: Да там целая страница посвящена использованию lp_solve из командной строки. Даже пример есть модели как и её LPSolve скормить - [http://lpsolve.sourceforge.net/5.5/lp_solve.htm](http://lpsolve.sourceforge.net/5.5/lp_solve.htm).

Comment: Спасибо большое, почитаю внимательнее! В основном про IDE читала.

Comment: Вроде прогрессирую. Но решить так и не получается. С английским не всё так хорошо. Написала приложение, которое создает из данных, введенных пользователем, файл с расширением .lp. Файл корректный. Если его открыть в LPSolve IDE, решает правильно. Подключила файл "lp_lib.h". Теперь можно использовать функции этой библиотеки для решения модели. Аргументом они принимают не файл, а указатель на модель. У меня модель большая, ограничений много. Мне кажется, сложно ее заново составить с помощью функций библиотеки lp_lib.h. Я бы хотела, чтоб решалась модель из файла. Не могу найти такую функцию.

Comment: Еще у меня командная строка почему-то не видит lp_solve.exe. Пишет, нет такой команды. Хотя в инструкции сказано просто скачать архив и распаковать. Библиотеку проект видит. Компилится.

Comment: Возможно надо добавить папку с lp_solve.exe в переменную окружения PATH, чтобы она была видна в консоли. По поводу моделей - я не специалист в LPSolve, помочь ничем не смогу =) Если добавление папки с lp_solve.exe в переменную PATH  не поможет вызывать её из командной строки, то вы всегда можете использовать полный путь к exe файлу для запуска этого файла. Пример использования lp_solve из командной строки видимо самый простой вариант скормить вашу модель (в виде файла) программе lp_solve.exe

Comment: Спасибо) Добавила папку в переменную Path. Считает. Результат расчета в консоли модели из файла, сформированного моей программой, совпадает с результатом, получаемым в LPSolve. Теперь буду пробовать запускать этот экзешник в своем приложении и записывать результат в файл)

Comment: Там может быть есть параметры у lp_solve.exe, позволяющие записать результат в файл. Без перенаправления (типа такого `dir > 1.txt`)

Comment: Получилось в консоли запускать lp_solve и записывать решение в файл.

Comment: Еще какая-то проблема с записью самой модели задачи, которую нужно решить, в файл. Нажимаю на кнопку, создается файл модели. Он корректный. Lp_solve IDE его нормально решает. Но если в той же кнопке написать команду для решения этой модели, то пишет, что в файле синтаксическая ошибка. Впечатление, что он становится корректным, только после того, как кнопка закончит выполняться.

Comment: А Вы пример кода добавьте в вопрос, и сам вопрос поправьте немного. Ну либо новый сделайте, а то мы тут в комментах целую переписку устроили. Может Вы файл забыли закрыть ?

Comment: FILE* file;
fopen_s(&file, fn, "w");
  fprintf(file, "min: x21;\n");
  fprintf(file, "...", ....); fclose(file);
 const char* cmnd1 = "lp_solve -s model1.lp >1.txt";
 system(cmnd1);

Comment: Полученный файл нормально решается с помощью lpsolve_ide, нормально решается этой командной в командной строке: lp_solve -s model1.lp >1.txt, решение записывается в файл. Т.е. не думаю, что проблема с файлом. Но когда запускаю этот код, пишет, что синтаксическая ошибка в файле (((